# How do you connect to wifi on Mac OS X

Tags: wireless, mac

When I installed ran Ubuntu 12.10 by live CD on my iMac, it could not connect to a WiFi network. When I click on the wiFi network button on the top bar it does not display any networks at all but I know there are at least 3 in my area. I don't know how old the iMac is.

Comment: Can you add outputs of the 'ifconfig' and 'lspci' to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have 12.04, but my guess is there is a similar solution.  If you have just installed Ubuntu and nothing else, it probably does not have the wifi drivers for your card pre-installed.  You will need to plug it in to an ethernet connection (for which it should have drivers) and then download the correct wifi driver that you need.  The recent versions of ubuntu, such as yours, should - probably - automatically download the correct wifi software...and then you can restart with the machine unplugged from ethernet and the wifi should work.  I say should...I had to do some tweaks to get it running and others have had to download and install the correct drivers "manually".

If you can't get the drivers installed or something else goes wrong, there are a LOT of questions on this board with solutions to wifi problems - do a search and read up.

Comment: I have dual boot Mac OS X and Ubuntu, not just Ubuntu.